# Как вывести сообщение после появления ошибки java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Java Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как вывести сообщение  после появления ошибки java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:  мол брат  у тебя закончилась память.

Comment: А в чем у вас затруднение? Поймать исключение и/или вывести пользователю ошибку?

Comment: Код, пожалуйста, в студию.

Comment: вывести пользователю ошибку

Comment: Ради интереса, а для чего это вам ? А так, в блоке try{}catch(Exception e){//выводите сообщение об ошибке }, и смотря с чем работаете, в rx обработка ошибок происходит иначе